# Session mix up - apache httpd with mod_jk, tomcat, spring security - serving data of other user

Tags: tomcat, spring-security, apache2, mod-jk

Recently we have faced a serious problem, that one user was served data of another user. This problem is almost impossible to reproduce.

We are using standard logged-users-management provided by Spring-security, and we are sure that the problem isn't in storing user in instance variable or similar concurrency stuff in our app.

We really doubt that the problem is in SpringSecurity or Tomcat itself.

Our front-server is apache httpd, connected to tomcat via ajp connector (mod_jk). We are not doing any load balancing (httpd cares just about SSL, some url rewrites and serving some php modules)

Here is our setup:

```
## OS
OS Name:        Linux 
OS Version:     2.6.32-5-686
Architecture:   i386

## Apache httpd
Server version: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Server built:   Sep  4 2011 20:27:42

## mod_jk
mod_jk/1.2.30 (installed via apt-get)

## JVM
JVM Version:    1.6.0_18-b18
JVM Vendor:     Sun Microsystems Inc.

## Tomcat
Server version: Apache Tomcat/6.0.28
Server built:   February 12 2011 1443
```

We blame httpd / mod_jk from this session mix up so our only solution would be to remove apache httpd. But before we leave this popular and widely used configuration, we would like to know if anyone has faced the similar problem.

The only similar problems I have found were in load ballancing or mod_jk.

Have you ever faced some similar problem?
Any hints, ideas, links or experience will be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You are not crazy, this is almost exactly the same situation I found myself in.  Please see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845493/spring-security-jsf-hibernate-accidental-session-hijacking-on-tomcat .  Did you ever find a solution to this or have any additional information?  I can share as much information as you want if you want to talk about it in chat.

Comment: I figured out what was causing this exact problem for me.  See my self answer in the comment above, it had to do with a difference between how managed beans work in JSF and Spring when you integrate Spring into a JSF project.

Comment: Hi maple_shaft, thanks for your post. Unfortunatelly in our case it is definitelly not bug in our code. Lucky for you.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible problems may be second login attempt.
Consider following case:

- User opens two browser tabs with two login forms.
- Tab 1: do login as user_1. Load some data into the HTTP session.
- Tab 2: do login as user_2. Load some data into the HTTP session.

In most browsers it will be the same HTTP session. So actually you will have data from user_1 and user_2 combined in one HTTP session. Any page that uses session objects may be affected.

You have two options here:

- Prevent this situation. Detect second login attempt and ask user to do logout first. It's easy with Spring Security, see code below.
- If you absolutely need one account per browser tab then you can store your session data in a map per username.

You can prevent second login attempt thanks to [Concurrent Session Control](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-concurrent-sessions) fetaure:

```
<http>
    ...
    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </session-management>
</http>
```

Is it already done in your application?

Comment: Hi Maksym, thanks for your answer, but this is definitely not our problem. User_1 was displayed data of User_2 and users were on different browsers, they were even geographicaly at different locations. I am affraid that this problem is more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you exclude the concurrent session problem then pretty much the only possibility is that your business logic itself is flawed, and serving another user's data. Please post code samples how the 'current user' is determined, and later used.

EDIT: bugs that manifest themselves only in production are often caused by race conditions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Ensure that your code uses local variables whenever possible, and employ locking/synchronization where applicable.

Comment: Hi rootkit007, thanks also. Our 'current user' is obtained in standard spring-security-style: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();` I am pretty sure that it is not a problem, it must be somewhere 'deeper' because the problem was reported only at production environment described above and also it is nearly impossible to reproduce.

Comment: Security context is stored in session. So it must one of 1. Sessions mixup (maybe URL that contains jsessionid was copied and pasted? do you use custom session manager? are your Tomcat sessions persisted?) 2. Spring security bug (highly unlikely) 3. Bug in business logic somewhere

Comment: I like the idea about URL with jsessionid. But it's not possible if you use default conf (see session fixation protection in the doc).

Comment: Maksym, you are correct to point out that its not possible with default conf. Still this is something that needs to be checked for, and configuration adjusted if neccessary

Comment: As I said, users were at different computers (even at geographicaly different locations), co copy-paste is not possible. Business Logic bug is highly unlikely, we are using same code accross all of our prod apps and only at that setup we were reported this bug.

Comment: 'Fraid there is nothing you (or anyone else) can do until you pinpoint what is it. I would suggest adding appropriate logging to your application and then dissect the logs next time this situation happens...

Comment: Hi rootkit, as I stated many times, bug is definitelly not in our app, so propriate logging wouldn't help anything. Bug is somewhere in lower levels. I am posting the answer of our solution, but unfortunatelly we can't be 100% sure that it fixes the bug.

Answer (score 1):

So far we were not able to reproduce the bug, but we have found that some people faced same problem with mod_jk:

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47714
- http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Spring-Security-after-log-in-user-changed-and-session-mixed-up-td4636714.html (at the bottom)

So now we are running with this settings:

- JkOptions DisableReuse : http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html
- worker retries = 0 : http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/workers.html#Advanced Worker Directives

And we are planning to switch mod_jk for mod_proxy_http.

I am leaving this question not-answered, because I can't assure (and nobody facing same problem was able to assure) that the solution fixes the bug.

If anyone could share any information, I would appreciate it a lot! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you integrate JSF and Spring, the JSF dependency injection conflicts with Spring dependency injection so Spring rewrote the JSF module that handles that to just wrap Spring DI instead. So when I declare a JSF ManagedBean as Session Scoped, I must also give it a `@Controller` annotation so that it is recognized as a Spring Bean as well.

[For More info, See this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14860933/455654)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem with Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and Mod_JK 1.2.19

You can reproduce the bug with a JMeter script and a good assertion.

Here is my blog post telling the story : http://jeecookbook.blogspot.com/2013/07/modjk-session-mixed-between-users.html

Using Mod_proxy with this assertion solve the problem : no more mixing detected.